# Division and multiplication that preserve Euclidean norms

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

I am looking for ways to define

$$\frac{1}{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n\quad \quad and\quad \quad  x\cdot y\in \mathbb{R}^n  ,$$
where $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that 
$$\left\|\frac{1}{x}\right\|=\frac{1}{\|x\|}\quad \quad and \quad \quad \|x \cdot y\|=\|x\|\|y\|,$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is the $n$-dimensional Euclidean norm. Moreover, I need for all $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}^n,$

1. $$(x\cdot y) \cdot z=x \cdot (y \cdot z)$$
2. $$x\cdot y=y \cdot x$$
3. $$x\cdot \frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{x}\cdot x=1,$$
   where $1$ is the identity of the operation $\cdot$ and 
   $\|1\|=1.$
4. $$ (\alpha x)\cdot y=\alpha (x \cdot y)=x \cdot (\alpha y),$$
   where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}.$

These are all I need.

We have this when $n=2.$ Using the devision and multiplication in complex numbers,
we can define 
$$\frac{1}{(a,b)}=\left(\frac{a}{a^2+b^2},\frac{-b}{a^2+b^2} \right)$$
and 
$$(a,b)\cdot (c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc).$$ Could somebody help me? Thank you so much.

Masih.

Comment: Did you want the distributive laws? Relevant to your question is the concept of composition algebra; see e.g. here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/composition+algebra

Comment: Thank you for your information. The link is very useful. I really appreciate your help. According to Hurwitz's theorem, Possible dimensions are only $1, 2, 4,$ and $8.$ Do I understand it correctly? Thank you.

Comment: (This is all under the assumption that you want the distributive laws, which were not mentioned in the post.)  Right, so this says the only possibilities are the real numbers, the complex numbers, the quaternions, and the octonions. Of course you have demanded associativity which rules out the octonions, and commutativity which rules out the quaternions. So there you have it.

Comment: I think that even if you *don't* include distributivity, the possible dimensions are 1, 2, 4, 8. This comes from deep work in algebraic topology due to J. Frank Adams (on the Hopf Invariant One Problem) which shows that the only spheres which admit an $H$-structure are of dimensions 1, 3, 5, 7.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: That result becomes relevant if you require the multiplication to be continuous, but the OP does not demand this.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Oops, so true.

Answer (score 5):

If we have such a multiplication, then $x\cdot y = |x|\, |y| (e_x\cdot e_y)$ and $x^{-1}=(1/|x|)e_x^{-1}$, so we can focus on the unit sphere. We are then asked to make $S^{n-1}$ an abelian group, with the extra property that
$$
(-u)\cdot v = u\cdot (-v) = - (u\cdot v)
$$
(this comes from requirement 4, with $\alpha=-1$). Conversely, such a group structure gives a multiplication with the desired properties.

The only (small) obstacle to this is the requirement on the antipodal points, but we can just decompose $S^{n-1}= A\dot{\cup}-A$, then map $A$ bijectively to $\{e^{i\varphi} : 0\le\varphi <\pi\}\subseteq S^1$ and map $-A$ to the corresponding antipodal points on $S^1$ and then use multiplication of complex numbers.

If a continuous multiplication is desired, then we're in trouble and Todd's comment applies.